# Worksheet cell format not working - Python

Tags: python, excel, format, openpyxl

I tried to format working sheet by using below code,
I want to to set the bgcolor of the cell if the text contains 'unknown' in '`Column G`' using `openpyxl`

```
    red_fill = PatternFill(bgColor="FFC7CE")
    dxf = DifferentialStyle(fill=red_fill)
    rule = Rule(type="containsText", operator="containsText", text="unknown", dxf=dxf)
    rule.formula = ['NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("unknown")))']
    workingsheet.conditional_formatting.add('G1:G100', rule)
```

But, not working.

**Edit:**

Please see the input and expected output

[image]

Comment: Please paste the entire code.

Comment: What libraries are you importing?

Comment: I want to use 'openpyxl'

Comment: I guess "entire code" refers to a fully working but minimal example.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example. Really is this your entire code??

Comment: Thank you. Now, insert the full code so we can help you. Only the code you pasted doesn't work.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin: Already posted entire code for formating and input data.